# PDFsharp and VB.NET Ximage.FromStream (FromStream is not a member of XImage)

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

I have been struggling using PDFsharp in VB.NET in order to create some PDF reports that need to be mailed.

I am stuck with the XImage.FromStream.  I am getting the not a member of XImage error and I haven't been able to figure out what specific library I should import in order to make it work or what else should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.  In VB.net you have to use Image.FromStream in order to work because for some reason that is unknown to me the XImage.FromStream doesn't work.

Here is the example of the solution.

```
Dim Picture as XImage
Picture = Image.FromStream(stream)
```

After this you can draw the picture inside a PDF anywhere you want.  I hope this can help anyone with my same issue.